# How to get an Object's Object in PHP

Tags: php, oop, object

I'm having some troubles with some object oriented programming in PHP.

I basically have a function within a class, which displays some text:

```
  public function text() {
       echo 'text';
    }
```

Now I want to store the function name in an arra,y so I can reference it later:

```
$functions = array('text_func' => 'text');
```

And in an other function I want to call the above function with the Array reference, so I did the following:

```
public function display() {
   $this->functions['text_func']();
}
```

The result will be basically:

```
text();
```

My question is that, how is it possible to make this function run? (The correct way it should be look like: `$this->text()`). However I can't do something like this, because it gives me an error:

```
$this->$this->functions['text_func']();
```

Any idea or solution for my problem?

Comment: you should call $this->display();

Answer (score 1):

The error message you carefully ignore probably warns you that `$this` cannot be converted to string. That gives you a pretty good clue of what's going on.

(Long answer is that method names are strings. Since PHP is loosely typed, when it needs a string it'll try to convert whatever you feed it with into string. Your class lacks a `__toString()` method, thus the error.)

You probably want this:

```
$this->{$this->functions['text_func']}();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from PHP.net that should help:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    function Variable()
    {
        $name = 'Bar';
        $this->$name(); // This calls the Bar() method
    }

    function Bar()
    {
        echo "This is Bar";
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$funcname = "Variable";
$foo->$funcname();  // This calls $foo->Variable()

?>
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing a lot of things. First of all, you can use the [magic constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__METHOD__` and `__CLASS__` to determine in which class type and method you are currently executing code.

Secondly, a `callable` in PHP [is defined as](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) either an `array` with an object instance or static class reference at index 0, and the method name at index 1, or since PHP 5.2 a fully qualified string such as `MyClass::myFunction`. You can only dynamically invoke functions stored as one of these types. You can use the type hint `callable` when passing them between functions.

Answer (score 0):

$this does not contain a reference for itself,  so you should try just

```
$this->display();
```

instead of

```
$this->$this->functions['text_func']();  // WRONG
```